# Why are my menu items too small or too big?

Tags: codenameone

I'm using the default theme, which I understand is effectively the theme for the platform.

If I put my menu items in the side menu, they show up way too small. If I put them in the overflow menu, the show up way too big. I don't know the UUIDs for the components that display them, so I don't know how to override the font. Here are some examples:

[image: side menu]

Here they are in a side menu. As you can see, about five of them fit in the width of a penny. These are too small to be usable.

.

[image: overflow menu]

Here they are in the overflow menu. They're enormous. I couldn't fit two of them in the width of a penny.

.

[image: Native Application Example]

Here are some menus from a native application. In this example, you can see both the side menus and the overflow menus, which are a little big bigger, but they're both about 3 to the width of a penny. This is a very sensible size for my phone.

.

I never see these objects in code, so I can't fiddle with their Style objects. And I can't find them in the Resource Editor. Can anyone tell me how I can get these to show up in a sensible size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the more modern flat themes (blue, red, orange), the older native themes needs to be updated to use the Toolbar and the side menu.
The style for the overflow is "Command" and for the side commands is "SideCommand" make sure the styles Fonts are declared using mm and not pixels to allow it to adjust to different resolutions.